# How salesforce role based team's cases work in case report

Tags: reporting, case, servicecloud

As a manager, I want to see only my cases and my direct repartee's case in Salesforce My teams open cases report. I have 3 other managers in my same role. We all are assigned in same role in role hierarchy. When I run report with 'My role based team's cases' filter. I see my data, My direct subordinates data as well as other managers (who are in the same role) and their subordinates data. Provided that:
- Case OWD settings is private
- We all have read access to each others data
- I cannot use case team as we already reach assignment rules governor limit.

How can I remove other managers data from my teams report using 'role based team's cases' filter?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a formula field on the case object that checks to see if the logged in user is on your team, then use this field to filter your reports and views.

```
Owner:User.Manager.Id = $User.Id || Owner:User.Id = $User.ManagerId || $User.Id = Owner:User.Id
```